# Hibernate doesn't create join table

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am encountering a problem which never happened to me before. I have `ManyToMany` relationship and Hibernate doesn't create the join table. It creates only entity tables. I am using SpringDataJpa with MySQL.

*Doctor entity:*

```
Entity
@Table(name = "doctors")
public class Doctor {
  @Id
  @Size(min = 11, max = 11)
  @NotNull
  private String pesel;

  @NotNull
  private String firstName;

  @NotNull
  private String lastName;

  private Long salary;

  @NotNull
  private String speciality;

  @OneToOne
  private Doctor supervisor;

  @ManyToMany
  @JoinTable(name = "doctors_treatments",
          joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pesel", referencedColumnName = "pesel"),
          inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "treatment_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
  private Set<Treatment> treatments;
}
```

*Treatment Entity:*

```
@Table(name = "treatments")
public class Treatment {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;

  @NotNull
  private String name;

  private Long cost;

  @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "treatments")
  private Set<Doctor> doctors; 
}
```

*application.properties*:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:33061/sys
```

*StackTrace:*

```
  org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    ...
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'sys.doctors_treatments' doesn't exist
```

Any ideas what could be the cause?

Comment: Well it clearly says that the table `doctors_treatments` doesn't exist. You are sure it exists?

Comment: No it doesn't. I want it to be created by Hibernate (like Doctor and Treatment tables)

Comment: You need to create the Entity first. At least, that is how I always do it.

Comment: Entity for the Join Table?

Comment: Yeah, it is still a table.

Comment: does the user have "create table" permission(the user that you create database connection with)?

Comment: yes, as I said, it created two tables but without the join table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that Hibernate didn't create join table because of *Doctors* primary key extending allowed size. It was however, able to create *Doctors* table alone. So in order to fix it I had to limit id size. I've changed *Doctors* id like this:

```
@Id
@Column(length = 11)
@NotNull
private String pesel;
```

And now join table can be created by Hibernate.