# Hibernate doesn't creating Join Table on his own

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I want to make many-to-many relationship between my entities. 
I want hibernate to generate this table automaticaly, but it's not gonna happen.
Here is my entities:

**DrugsEntity**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "drugs", schema = "meds", catalog = "chinamed")
public class DrugsEntity {
    @Id
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name_eng")
    private String nameEng;

    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(name = "drug_symptom",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "drug_id",nullable = false) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "symptom_id", nullable = false) })
    private Set<SymptomEntity> symptoms;
}
```

**SymptomsEntity:**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "symptom",schema = "meds", catalog = "chinamed")
public class SymptomEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int id;

    @Basic
    String name;

    @Column
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "symptoms",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<DrugsEntity> drugs;
}
```

Some configuration:

```
jpa:
hibernate:
  ddl-auto: update
show-sql: true
```

So i can see hibernate sql queries:

```
Hibernate: create table meds.diseases (disease_id int4 not null, drug_id int4, name varchar(255), primary key (disease_id))
Hibernate: create table meds.drugs (id int4 not null, action_pharm varchar(255), action_tkm varchar(255), clinic varchar(255), contraindications varchar(255), form varchar(255), maker varchar(255), name_eng varchar(255), name_ru varchar(255), taking_method varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: create table meds.herbal_drug (herbal_id int4 not null, drug_id int4, primary key (herbal_id))
Hibernate: create table meds.pattern_drug (pattern_id int4 not null, drug_id int4, primary key (pattern_id))
Hibernate: create table meds.symptom (id int4 not null, name varchar(255), primary key (id))
Hibernate: alter table if exists symptom_drug add constraint FKl7jx9kgpfiunb1r5neejqi1in foreign key (drug_id) references meds.symptom
Hibernate: alter table if exists symptom_drug add constraint FKimmnf4263cgg3yg46i90tkn1g foreign key (symptom_id) references meds.drugs
Hibernate: alter table if exists symptom_drugs add constraint FKnvs2tystmth11i573t29rtayk foreign key (drugs_id) references meds.drugs
Hibernate: alter table if exists symptom_drugs add constraint FKng4i6ig5nr2laew225ttfnrb9 foreign key (symptom_entity_id) references meds.symptom
```

As I see hibernate dont even try to create this table.

```
Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect
```

How can achive that hibernate create that table on his own?

P.S: already looked this link [Hibernate doesn't create join table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52910621/hibernate-doesnt-create-join-table) But it isn't my case, i suppose.

**SOLVED:**
The problem was that this table was alredy crated. And I probably coud notice something interesting in hibernate's queries: there was no prefix "meds" before drug_symptom table name.
So it created table in "public" schema of databese.
Solved that this way: added default_schema

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        default_schema: meds
```

But also I could use "schema" parameter in annotation @JoinTable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove @Column annotation from drugs field and define cascade type on DrugsEntity.symptoms, as it is the owning side of relationship.

Both @JoinTable and @ManyToMany annotations should not be used with @Column, as the mapping must be made by it's own definition. Hibernate gets confused about both annotations on same field.

Your mapping should be:

```
 @Entity
 @Table(name = "drugs", schema = "meds", catalog = "chinamed")
 public class DrugsEntity {
      @Id
      @Column(name = "id")
      private int id;

     @Basic
     @Column(name = "name_eng")
     private String nameEng;

     @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
     @JoinTable(name = "drug_symptom",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "drug_id",nullable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "symptom_id", nullable = false))
     private Set<SymptomEntity> symptoms;
 }
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "symptom",schema = "meds", catalog = "chinamed")
public class SymptomEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int id;

    @Basic
    String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "symptoms")
    Set<DrugsEntity> drugs;
}
```

Good coding!

Comment: Removed. Nothing changed.

Comment: One more thing: you must define all mapping information on the "owning" side of your entities (DrugsEntity.symptoms) and remove the Column annotation also from Symptom.drugs entity. I've just tried your mapping here using hibernate 5.14 and eclipselink 2.7.4 and everthing worked like a charm. Edited answer to reflect this comment.

Comment: still no changes. Its strange...  Maybe its Postgresql-side problem... But the case is that Hibernate doesn't even try to create that jointable. It start to creating constraints for non-existing table as you can see in sql queries that I put in my question

Comment: Lol! it IS CREATING, but surprisingly it crated new schema and create it there. Thanks much, seems that there was no actualy problem.